# What is the difference between 明确 and 清楚?

Tags: difference

Both mean "clear", but in what way these two words are different?

Comment: @user6065 Unless the "user6065" account is auto-scripting answers and comments, there is no requirement for a question body text to repeat the characters from the heading in the question in Chinese SE policy. Please stop asking this from new users.

Comment: it would just mean doing a favour to users answering the question, being able to copy Chinese from question w/o using Chinese typing software would make writing answer easier

Comment: @user6065 You can copy text from heading, even they are inside a hyper-link. I did a simple test and found that you can select the text while pressing "Alt", on Windows in Chrome. You can then copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 明 = bright = clear (you see thing clearly in bright light)
>
> 确 = definite; unambiguous = clear (when there is no ambiguity, it is clear)
>
> **明确** = clear (**clear and definite/ unambiguous**)

~

> 清 = clear (when water is clear,  you can see things in it clearly)
>
> 楚 = neat = detailed; comprehensive (when things are neatly displayed, you can see the details)
>
> **清楚** = clear (**clear and detailed/ comprehensive**)

Example:

明确指引 - clear (and unambiguous) guidelines

清楚指引 - clear (and detailed) guidelines

目標明确 -  the goal is clear (and unambiguous)

目標清楚 - the goal is clear (and comprehensive)

More detailed example:

清楚說説每一個細節 - Clearly explain every detail (*everything you can think of and everything you can't think of is explained*)

明确指出今次行動的目標 - Clearly point out the target of this mission (*pointing out and confirm that guy is our target*)

Simply put, just remember  "明确" as unambiguously clear;  "清楚" as comprehensively clear.

Of course, the English word 'clear' implies both 'unambiguous' (e.g. *it is clearly him*) and 'comprehensive' (*e.g. everything clear?*). That's why both  "明确" and "清楚" can be translated as "clear"

Answer (score 0):

You might say, if you were looking at an object: 我看得清楚。

but not: 我看得明确。

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a short answer:

清楚: Your eyes or ears feel clear;

明确: Your mind feels clear.